# Repeat timed USEREVENT sequence in Pygame event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[image: enemy ai chart]

**what i am trying to achieve**
I am attempting to get the enemy to do a set of movements with a picture swap that are timed and in a ordered sequence that repeats.

the timing is not doing milliseconds?

**what is happening**
After a long time the enemy does first movement then long pause images some times swap sometimes not.

I am not getting any exceptions or errors when I run it.

Also when I add the userevent into the game loop above the keydown events I break the player movement.

[Github to images and full code](https://github.com/taylorjohn/knock_d_out)
Below is the most successful of the things I tried so far

I created the desired numbered USEREVENT in ordered sequence

```
# Create a bunch of AI events 
ai_uppercut_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
ai_l_punch_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
ai_r_punch_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 3
ai_r_dodge_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 4
ai_l_dodge_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 5
```

Gave the enemy ai character a start position

```
enemy_x = 235
enemy_y = 145
```

gave the enemy ai a movement amount

```
aimovex = 40
aimovey = 40
```

defined the images to swap out for the different moves

```
# Define ai images for different moves
enemy_default  = pygame.image.load("enemy_default.png")
ai_uppercut_image = pygame.image.load("enemy_uppercut.png")
ai_l_punch_image = pygame.image.load("enemy_left.png")
ai_r_punch_image = pygame.image.load("enemy_right.png")
ai_r_dodge_image = pygame.image.load("enemy_dodge_right.png")
ai_l_dodge_image = pygame.image.load("enemy_dodge_left.png")
```

set up the clock and tick and timer for events

```
# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() 

# set timer for the ai movement events
pygame.time.set_timer(ai_uppercut_event, MOVE_UPPERCUT)
pygame.time.set_timer(ai_l_punch_event, MOVE_PUNCH_LEFT)
pygame.time.set_timer(ai_r_punch_event, MOVE_PUNCH_RIGHT)
pygame.time.set_timer(ai_r_dodge_event, MOVE_DODGE_RIGHT)
pygame.time.set_timer(ai_l_dodge_event, MOVE_DODGE_LEFT)
```

in the main event loop

```
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------

paused  = False
running = True

while running:
    # --- Main Event Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == ai_uppercut_event:
            aimovex =+ 80
            activeEnemyImage = ai_uppercut_image

        elif event.type == ai_l_punch_event:
            aimovex =+ 80
            activeEnemyImagee = ai_l_punch_image

        elif event.type == ai_r_punch_event:
            aimovex =- 80
            activeEnemyImage = ai_r_punch_image

        elif event.type == ai_r_dodge_event:
            aimovey =+ 80
            activeEnemyImage = ai_r_dodge_image

        elif event.type == ai_l_dodge_event:
            aimovey =- 80
            activeEnemyImage = ai_l_dodge_image 

        enemy_x += aimovex
        enemy_y += aimovey

        #elif event.type == reloaded_event:
            # when the reload timer runs out, reset it
            #reloaded = True
            #pygame.time.set_timer(reloaded_event, 0)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                paused = not paused

        # --- Event Processing ---

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                movex =- 40
                activeCharacterImage = player_left

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                movex =+ 40
                activeCharacterImage = player_right
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue has to do with your doubled event polling loops:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == ai_uppercut_event:
        # ...
```

Because there are two loops, you'll often have your events lost to the first loop which only checks if they're `QUIT` events and ignores all other kinds of events.

To fix this, combine the two loops and use an `elif` for the first non-`QUIT` event check:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    elif event.type == ai_uppercut_event:
        # ...
```

Comment: awesome thanks first time combining the two types together. That should be easy to remember that going forward...